# How to make Module Functions access a Class context in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use a more object oriented approach with node.js "embedding" functions ( if that is the right word )  so that I can use functions and objects as if they are in the objects context.  It might be easier to show in code.

I realise you can assign individual functions in the constructor - and this would work.. but I am not sure how to assign a whole module with functions to all the functions can access values in the objects context.

So ,  my question is : How can I assign a module to a class so that all the functions within the module can access everything within the objects context.

app.js

```
const myFunctions = require('./functions');

class myClass{
    constructor() {
        this.myFunctions = myFunctions ;
    }
}

var mc = new myClass();
mc.myObject = { aaa: 'test'}
mc.myFunctions.outputValue(); // << should output the previous value set.
```

functions.js

```
function outputValue(){
    console.log(this.myObject)
}
module.exports = {
    outputValue
}
```

Comment: `Object.assign(this, myFunctions)` ... `mc.outputValue()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two ways:

1 - Bound your class instance `this` to each one of the external functions:

```
class myClass {
  constructor() {
    this.myFunctions = {
      outputValue: myFunctions.outputValue.bind(this),
    };
  }
}
```

2 - Define a method in your class to call the external functions, like:

```
class myClass {
  constructor() {
  }

  callFunction(fnName) {
    const fn = myFunctions[fnName];

    if (fn) fn.apply(this);
  }
}
```

Said that I will recommend avoiding using classes and `this` at all (at least it's completely necessary) and instead use pure functions, functions that only receive parameters does some processing and return some value.

Comment: That's fine. as I understand it classes are just "syntactical sugar" to coin an often used phrase..?   I just wanted to be able to add a whole module without having to add all the functions individually. e.g.  instead of 
    this.function = myfunction
    this.function2 = myfunction2
I wanted to say 
    this.functions = myModulewithfunctions

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this which also follows the injection pattern,

```
const myClass = new myClass(myFunctions);
myClass.outputValue.bind(myClass);
```

Here it binds and inject all the class objects so it is accessible to other methods in different class .

Note : Look at **"bind"** usage.